# Output from array to speaker (CreatePlayer, J2ME)

Tags: java-me

I cannot find simple code that ouput sound just from array through speaker on J2ME platform (I know that CreatePlayer class need WAV header with parameters).

```
int[] wav_hdr = {0x52,0x49,0x46,0x46,
                 0xC6,0x0F,0x00,0x00,
                 0x57,0x41,0x56,0x45,
                 0x66,0x6D,0x74,0x20,
                 0x12,0‌x00,0x00,0x00,
                 0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,
                 0x40,0x1F,0x00,0x00,
                 0x40,0x1F,0x00,0x00,
                 0x01,0x00,0x08,0x00,
                 0x00,0x00,0x64,0x61,
                 0x74,0x61,0xA0,0x0‌​F,
                 0x00,0x00};\\ wav header

byte[] adata = new byte[wav_hdr.length+4000];

for(int i=0; i<wav_hdr.length; i++) {
  adata[i] = (byte)wav_hdr[i];
}

Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new ByteArrayInputStream(adata), "audio/x-wav"); 
player.start();
```

Comment: Thanks ALL!! My code is now:  int[] wav_hdr = 0x52,0x49,0x46,0x46,0xC6,0x0F,0,0,0x57,0x41,0x56,0x45,0x66,0x6D,0x74,0x20,0x12,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0x40,0x1F,0,0,0x40,0x1F,0,0,1,0,8,0,0,0,0x64,0x61,0x74,0x61,0xA0,0x0F,0,0};\\ wav header    byte[] adata = new byte[wav_hdr.length+4000]; for(int i=0; i<wav_hdr.length; i++){ adata[i] = (byte)wav_hdr[i];} Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new ByteArrayInputStream(adata), "audio/x-wav"); player.start();

Comment: I don't see any actual data being added to the array after you insert the wav-header.